# Capture data from pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, apache-tika

### Just assume this is my pdf file

AGENCIES: Office of the Comptroller of the Currency, Treasury; and the Board of Governors
of the Federal Reserve System.

ACTION: Final rule.

SUMMARY: The Office of the Comptroller of the Currency and Board of Governors of the
Federal Reserve System (Board).

DATES: Effective date: January 1, 2014. Mandatory compliance date: January 1, 2014 for
advanced approaches banking organizations that are not savings and loan holding companies.

---

If User selected keyword as AGENCIES it should retrieve..
Office of the Comptroller of the Currency, Treasury; and the Board of Governors
of the Federal Reserve System.
Like 
If User selected keyword as ACTION it should retrieve..
Final rule.
and so on .....
How to do this one?
Can any one please help.

Comment: You have got a good library to read pdf.  I guess you should write some code now

Comment: Dont know how to proceed can you please suggest any ideas..?

Comment: Yes like Jayan said, read the docs and get coding...